# does bootstrap multiselect v1.1.2 works on the latest bootstrap version?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-multiselect

I have all the necessary files but on click cannot see the dropdown menu list

I am using [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) on latest Bootstrap version and I can see my options list in inspector but when I click on it, it is not showing me a list. All the required files and scripts of jquery , bootstrap and multiselect are there but it is not showing me the list.

I have read all the documentation and compared my code with it but it's not working. The same is working in bootstrap there. It is adding one more class in dropup class which is open and showing the list. in bootstrap 5.3.2 it is not doing the same, in fact it is doing nothing

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.